# Aggregating attributes from line to point using QGIS Expression

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, vector-layer, aggregation, relationship-class

I have two feature classes: point and line. The purpose is to make geometrical relations between them. For instance, if points are on line then they automatically take attributes from a specific field from line layer (field-double).

But if i'm not giving any attribute it returns `NULL` (but it should aggregate from layer). What is wrong with expression?

```
if(NULL,
    aggregate(
        layer:='layer_you_want',
        aggregate:='concatenate',
        expression:=to_string("field_you_want"),
        concatenator:=', ',
        filter:=intersects($geometry, buffer(geometry(@parent), 0.0005))
        ),
    "remain_the_same_field"
    )
```

Comment: Can't work because condition in if-clause is `NULL`, but you don't tell **what** is `NULL`. Then again, it's unclear what you want to achieve... can you add a screenshot? If a point is on a line, you want to aggregate... what? Aggregate is to bring together attributes from different features, so each point would get values from several lines. This is unclear to me.

Comment: in my case, it is valve(point) and waterpipe(polyline).
when I put valve on waterpipe I need it to take diameter from waterpipe if I'm not giving another value for valve diameter.

if(NULL,aggregate(
 layer:= 'waterpipe',
 aggregate:='concatenate',
 expression:=to_string("diameter"),
 concatenator:=', ',
 filter:= intersects($geometry,buffer( geometry(@parent),0.0005)
 )), "diameter_valve")

I wrote the code in layer properties- valve diameter feature-default value

Comment: You didn't answer the questions. Without making clear what you want to achieve, you won't geht a meaningful answer. Why Aggregate? You just want to geht the diamer of the Piper, right? You want **one** value, not several Differenz values per point? How should the result look like?

Comment: It's not necessary to use aggregate, it just works for me in another case. 
Yes, I want to get the diameter of the pipe if I don't give another value instead. 
Yes, I want one value for one point.  the result should look in point feature - or my entered diameter, or aggregated diameter from line(if I don't give another value), or NULL(if it missing in both cases).

Comment: "if I don't give another value": and where does this "other value" come from...? Is it an attribute of the point layer?

Comment: yes, at the time of creation if I don't give the value in an attribute table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following expression on the point layer and adapt it to your needs. It checks whether the point layer's attribute named `value` is 0:

- If not, the current value of `value` will be returned.
- if `value = 0`, the expression returns the value of the attribute called `name` of the line layer `waterpipe` - but only if the point is on the line (you should set a very small tolerance for the distance from the line, here 0.01). If points are not on the line, `NULL` will be returned

```
if (
    "value"=0,  -- set a condition
    overlay_nearest(
        'waterpipe',  -- name of the line layer
        name,  -- name of the attribute of the point layer
        max_distance:=0.01  -- small tolerance distance
    )[0],
    value
)
```

*Red label is generated by the expression:*
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This one also worked:

```
if("diameter_valve" is NULL,
    aggregate(
        layer:='waterpipe_pipe',
        aggregate:='concatenate',
        expression:=to_string("diameter"),
        concatenator:=', ',
        filter:=intersects($geometry, buffer(geometry(@parent), 0.0005))
        ),
    "diameter_valve"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression worked for me:

```
if("diameter_valve" is NULL,
    overlay_nearest('waterpipe', diameter_pipe, max_distance:=0.01)[0],
    "diameter_valve"
    )
```